# move a file, replacing existing (if any), ideally by putting existing in the trash

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, trash

I am trying to find a way to automatically (without user intervention) move a file from A to B, replacing B if it exists, ideally by putting the existing copy of B into the appropriate Trash folder.

This will be done in a shell script. Eventually A and B will beed to be `$VARIABLES` like this:

```
/usr/bin/osascript <<EOT
tell application "Finder"
    move POSIX file "$SOURCE" to POSIX file “$DEST" with replacing
end tell
EOT
```

***but*** I can’t even get this to work without variables, such as this:

```
/usr/bin/osascript <<EOT
tell application "Finder"
    move POSIX file "/Users/luomat/Desktop/1.txt" to POSIX file "/Users/luomat/Desktop/2.txt" with replacing
end tell
EOT
```

I took that syntax pretty much directly from [Stackoverflow 14058061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058061/move-a-file-in-finder-with-applescript) but I get this result:

```
24:132: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

I also came across [a MacTech article](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.20/20.11/MoreFinderScripting/index.html) which suggested using `replacing true` so I tried:

```
/usr/bin/osascript <<EOT
tell application "Finder"
    move POSIX file "/Users/luomat/Desktop/1.txt" to POSIX file "/Users/luomat/Desktop/2.txt" replacing true
end tell
EOT
```

but it still says:

```
24:132: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

Please note that [stackoverflow #12708195](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708195/i-am-trying-to-tell-finder-to-move-files-with-applescript-but-i-dont-know-how) I am not trying to prompt the user to do this, but ideally would like it to happen ‘automagically’ as the kids say.

**So… what am I doing wrong and/or missing?**  Trying to Google for information on error code (-10000) pretty much tells me that it means “AppleScript failed” which isn’t all that helpful.

Comment: Technically it's more like an AppleScript, and it's not the easiest thing to do when combining it sometimes; Any reason you're not doing it entirely as a shell script?

Comment: It's going to be part of a much larger shell script, this is only a small piece of it.

Answer (score 1):

I need to do some more research to get this right.  I feel like its close, but applescript still doesn't like it.  Maybe it will give you some ideas until I get back here to give it another shot.  Btw this is going to be so much easier when you are using the choose file dialog.

heres my non-working (yet) attempt.  If you don't be me to it ill try to finish the solution tomorrow.

```
# 1. get desktop folder
set desktopFolder to (((path to desktop from user domain) as string)) as alias


# 2.set source file
tell application "Finder" to ¬
set theFile to ((path to file "1.text" of folder (desktopFolder)) as string) as   alias


# 3.set destination file
tell application "Finder" to ¬
set theDestination to ((path to file "2.text" of folder (desktopFolder)) as string) as alias



# 4.make it happen
tell application "Finder" to move theFile to theDestination with replacing
```